# SQLRPGLE DB2 Select into variable

Tags: select, db2

I'm having problems with my query returning errors. What I have at this moment is this:

```
comi            C                   X'7D'
SqlQuery        S            500A        
VarSel          S             10A 

VarSel = *blanks;                                         
SqlQuery = 'select USU into VarSel from FXXUSELN ' +      
           'where USU = upper(' + comi + %trim(pusuario) +
           comi + ') and PWDUSU = upper(' + comi +        
           %trim(ppassword) + comi + ')';                 
Exec SQL execute immediate :SqlQuery;                     

psqlcod = sqlcod;
```

But when I try to debug that code, it returns -084: UNACCEPTABLE SQL STATEMENT as sqlcod. Printing the SqlQuery variable in the debugger call I get this string, which seems to be correct:

```
select USU into VarSel from FXXUSELN where USU = upper('usua
rio') and PWDUSU = upper('password')
```

Anybody knows how to solve this problem so I can make a login stored procedure? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that SELECT INTO can not be dynamically prepared.

If you look at the **Invocation** section of `SELECT INTO` in the [manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzhselin.htm) you'll see:

> This statement can only be embedded in an application program. It is an executable statement that cannot be dynamically prepared. It must not be specified in REXX.

Also note the following [Actions Allowed on SQL Statements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzactallow.htm) section of appendix B in the manual which summarizes where/how each statement may be used.

Finally, if what you tried had worked, you'd have opened yourself up to **SQL Injection** attacks.  Generally speaking, for any DB you should avoid dynamic SQL.  If you must use dynamic SQL, then you should use parameter makers instead of directly concatenating user input into the string.

In your case, there's no need for dynamic SQL if the first place.  Static SQL is easier, safer, and allows the use of `SELECT INTO`

```
exec SQL
  select USU into :VarSel from FXXUSELN       
   where USU = upper(:pusuario)
          and PWDUSU = upper(:ppassword);
```